# Map a SignalProducer that contains an error to return a NoError

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-swift

I am working with **ReactiveSwift 3.x** in an iOS project and have been unable to map over an error provided by one `SignalProducer` into a different one.

My `NoError SignalProducer` is:

```
func foo() -> SignalProducer<Void, NoError>
```

The function being called within `foo()` that I want to map is:

```
func bar() -> SignalProducer<Data, MyError>
```

I currently have the following:

```
func foo() -> SignalProducer<Void, NoError> {
    // Stuff happens here...
    return bar()
        .map({ _ -> Void in
            return ()
        })
        .mapError({ error -> NoError in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            // I do not want to handle this error
            return NoError
        })
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> 'mapError' produces 'SignalProducer< Void, F >', not the expected 
>    contextual result type 'SignalProducer< Void, NoError >'

Ultimately, I just want to print out the error, and then return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quack.

I had attempted some flatMapError work earlier, but got it to work with the following:

```
.flatMapError({ error -> SignalProducer<Void, NoError> in
    return SignalProducer.empty
    })
```